# Rounding up values and putting it in another element

Tags: javascript

my code below does what its suppose to do with one little problem. i have sat up for hours trying to fix it. could anyone help me out please.

```
var price = new Array(12.121212, 45.334, 2.34, 0);

for (var i=0;i<price.length;i++){
        roundPrice[i] = Math.round(price[i]*100)/100;
    }

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
            if (s[i].className == 'price') {//changed this to get class instead
                    s[i].value = roundPrice[0];
            }

        }
```

the line that is giving me a headache is

```
s[i].value = roundPrice[1];
```

if i state the actual index of the array, it puts that single value into all the input element specified.

on the other hand, if i use this line of code (below), i get 'undefined ' as a result in all the element specified.

```
s[i].value = roundPrice[i];
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you have more than one element with `id="price"`? That is not allowed, so it can give unexpected results.

Comment: @Guffa: I have changed it to class="price" but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 4 values in roundPrice (which get it's values directly from `price[]`), and possibly more in `s[]`, which is the input elements on the page.

Also, you are checking if the `input` element has an id of 'price' and only then you set the value. That should happen only once, as the id attribute is suppose to be unique for each element in the DOM.

If you only have 4 input elements in the page, and you plan on placing the values from `price[]` into them, remove the `if (s[i].id == 'price') {` and it's closing `}`.

Also, you should initialize your `roundPrice[]` array at the top with `var roundPrice = new Array();`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var price = [12.121212, 45.334, 2.34, 0]
var roundPrice = [0, 0, 0, 0];
```

instead of your first line.
PS i'm not sure whilch is the prefered way for arrays `new array()` or `[]`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfSWQ/

Also since you are setting an id. you could just do a `document.getElementById("price") which will return null or the element. (only 1 element). Which should work better and quicker than looping through all of them.

Comment: you are right, but the thing is i have more than 1 input element that i want to change. and i don't think you can get element by class :(.

Comment: @Govnah you'd need to use a framework like jQuery or Sizzle for that. I'd recommend jQuery. I use it a lot and its easy to learn. The code i wrote in the first lines will work either way.

Comment: jquery would ave done it easily. But i'm working on a class project, i'm not allowed to use jquery.

Comment: @Govnah Doh! well plain old javascript will still do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will do this, with assumption price and the input is the same

```
var price = new Array(12.121212, 45.334, 2.34, 0);
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0;i<price.length;i++){
        var roundPrice = Math.round(price[i]*100)/100;

        if (s[i].id == 'price') {
                s[i].value = roundPrice;
            }

    }
```

Hope helps

:)